# Are nucleons, atoms and molecules identical particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, identical-particles

Why are nucleons, atoms and molecules considered identical particles (bosons or fermions) even if they can be distinguished by the state of their most elementary components?

Also, what size does a molecule have to be so we can we cease to consider two molecules of that specie identical?

Comment: Buckyballs (C$_{60}$ molecules) have been shown to create an interference pattern.

Comment: @Pieter I think you need to explain *why* an interference pattern is significant in this context.

Comment: @undead, you are wrong. nucleons, atoms and molecules are not identical particles. Also, all molecules of one particular substance are identical.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/275363/are-there-fields-corresponding-to-the-composite-particles-e-g-hydrogen-atom-fi

Comment: Are you asking why a neutron is considered identical to a neutron, and a water molecule identical to a water molecule? Or are you thinking that a neutron is identical to a water molecule, which is false?

Comment: OP referred to "molecules of that specie", and that is quite clear.

Comment: @Ben Crowell, I know that neutrons and water molecules are not identical, this is not my question... My point is that neutrons can eventually be distinguished from one another by the internal states of their quarks. So it seems that considering them identical is an approximation. My question is at which point this approximation breaks up.

Comment: This explanation is pretty good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles#Distinguishing_between_particles. Notice that whereas in principle you can never distinguish identical particles, in some cases you can. See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377078/making-indistinguishable-particles-distinguishable/377270#377270. Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/283682/theoretically-could-there-be-different-types-of-protons-and-electrons

Comment: @nielsnielsen - only if all the atoms in the molecules are the same isotopes of course...

Comment: @jon custer, thanks, I get that, but the content of OP's question didn't seem to go there.

Comment: @valerie thank you for the references, these are instructive, but still not do not answer my specific question. Should the question be made clearer in some way? Because right now I don't understand why people are voting to close it down